# Why won't a [(ngModel)] of a radio group bind?

Tags: javascript, angular, radio-button, angular-ngmodel, ng-bootstrap

I'm using [`ng-bootstrap ngbRadioGroup`](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/buttons) as follows:

```
<div>
  <label>Deductible:</label>
  <div class="radio-group" [(ngModel)]="transaction.isDeductible" ngbRadioGroup name="isDeductible">
    <label class="btn btn-secondary"><input type="radio" [value]="true">Yes</label>
    <label class="btn btn-secondary"><input type="radio" [value]="false">No</label>
  </div>
</div>
```

Unfortunately, selecting one of the options does not set the `transaction.isDeductible` property.

What could be the problem?

Thanks in advance for any insights, let me know if I could provide additional relevant information :)

## EDIT:

Might be worth nothing this happens with two more RadioGroups, i provided the simplest one here

Comment: The problem is that `<div>` is not an input control and `ngModel` only supports input controls or components that implement `ControlValueAccessor`.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Hey Gunter, please take a look at the ngbRadioGroup link, it provides an example containing this exact structure :|

Comment: I missed that this is ng-bootstrap

Comment: Did you add the ng-bootstrap module to `imports: [...]`?

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Yes, it is imported as follows : `NgbModule.forRoot()`

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer Might be worth noting, that I tried placing the ngModel on each `input`, same results :/

Comment: Sorry, no idea. Maxbe someone else.

Comment: I'm having the same issue, I want to subscribe to ngModelChange

Comment: Did you find an answer for this @KesemDavid

Comment: @DavidCruwys Hey David, I literaly have no clue why did this suddenly happen.. I left the `ng-bootstrap` radios and am now using the basic ones. Please let me know if you found something interesting, I'll be more than happy to know why did that happen

Answer (score 1):

For me, removing the `../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.js` line from `angular-cli.json` scripts include fixed the issue. Obviously this isn't a fix for everyone if you need Bootstrap JavaScript!

So there must be a conflict between ng-bootstrap and the Bootstrap JavaScript. I don't have the time to look into it at the moment, maybe someone else could? I may comeback to this if I need to use it.

Answer (score 0):

Without seeing your module for imports and your component it is hard to know for sure what might be wrong, but usually when I had issues with two-way data-binding it was because I forgot to import`FormsModule` or forgot the `name` field on an input.

I have pasted your code in as-is to a Plunkr and confirmed that it is working, which shows that the template syntax is accurate and that your example has not provided enough definitive information to provide the correct answer - but you should be able to reference the component and module imports to confirm you have everything you need.

http://plnkr.co/edit/vHeyjHiHjawMLNiNXXk3?p=preview